# Angular 4 Environment Setup

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-2015

How to setup the angular 4 Environment in Visual studio 2015?

is node js installation mandatory for the angular4 development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need npm as a packagemanager. Npm is installed through the nodejs installation. So you need nodejs yes.

Install [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) through npm. 
The cli will help you to create the project.